# Add class to tr in table (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table><tr id="table_row_28" row="28"><td col="0" >test</td><td col="2">935.88959615384601</td></tr></table>
```

How do I add a class to the above table row with id eTable_row_28? I have tried the following whithout success

```
$("#table_row_28").addClass("test");
 $("#table_row_28").addClass("test tr");
```

**Edit.**

Found the problem, the element wasn't created when I called the function to add the class name. I'm not used to web developing. In a perfect world I would get an error that I'm trying to add a class to a nonexsisting element, that wasn't the case here. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Your first attempt should have worked. Are you wrapping your code in a [`$(document).ready()` block](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: Define "without success": is'nt that class actually added or doesn't it have effect?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gqdvwyuo/

Comment: I thought it did. Its really strange that it don't work. I have included JQuery so thats not the trouble. The problem is that it just don't add the table row class.

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/f3uL4h2y/.

Everything you asked was worked for me. Make sure you are including jQuery library for this;

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#table_row_28").addClass("test");
        $("#table_row_28").addClass("test tr");
    });
</script>
```